# Django: Handling cases where user enters wrong URL patterns to result in 404

Tags: django

How can i prevent the user from entering in url values that does not exist in database. For instance cars have an id, so to navigate to a car would be 
`http://127.0.0.1:8000/car/1`, and if user enters an id that does not exist then it returns 404, how can i handle this?

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('index.urls')),
    path('cars/', include('car.urls')),
    path('users/', include('user.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

This is a part of my Car view, because i have search_car too and that is kinda long:

```py
def get_car_by_id(request, id):
    cars = Car.objects.all()
    car_types = CarCategory.objects.all()
    context = {'apartments': apartments, 'car_types': car_types,
               'car': get_object_or_404(Car, pk=id)}
    return render(
        request, 'car/single_car.html', context
    )
```

Comment: You should check for that in view. Provide your cars `views.py`.

Comment: Shouldn't crash from what you've posted. Maybe you mistake 404 error for crash?

Comment: @Gasanov that's correct, prevent from entering something that does not exist which will return 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def get_car_by_id(request, id):
    cars = Car.objects.all()
    car_types = CarCategory.objects.all()
    context = {'apartments': apartments, 'car_types': car_types,
               'car': get_object_or_404(Car, pk=id)}
    return render(
        request, 'car/single_car.html', context
    )
```

You are using the `get_object_or_404` shortcut. This is a common approach, and means that Django will show the 404 page instead of crashing when the object does not exist. You will only see the real 404 page when `DEBUG = False` in your settings. When you have `DEBUG = True` then you will see the yellow 404 page to help debug the problem.

If you really don't want to display the 404 page, then you shouldn't use `get_object_or_404`. You could catch the `DoesNotExist` exception instead.

```
def get_car_by_id(request, id):
    cars = Car.objects.all()
    car_types = CarCategory.objects.all()
    try:
        car = Car.objects.get(pk=id)
    except Car.DoesNotExist:
        car = None
    context = {'apartments': apartments, 'car_types': car_types,
               'car': car }
    return render(
        request, 'car/single_car.html', context
    )
```

Now you can check `{% if car %}` in your template, and display a suitable error message.